# Disable the reload button on the browser and do not include information in the browser history for a html page

Tags: javascript, html

The following code creates a HTML page that a user receives a random number by clicking on the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>random page</title>
 <style type = "text/css">
 fieldset {
  width: 600px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
 }
 label {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 1em;
  clear: left;
 }
 span {
  float: left;
 }
 button {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin: auto;
 }
 </style>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
 var doRoll = true;

 function roll(){
  if(doRoll)
  {
  //create variables for form elements

  var spnCode = document.getElementById("spnCode");
  //get random number

  //get the ceiling
  var code = 1325 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 36);
  spnCode.innerHTML = code;
  doRoll = false;
 }
 } // end roll
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>random number</h1>
 <form>
  <fieldset>

   <label>code</label>
   <span id = "spnCode">0</span>
   <button type = "button"
     onclick = "roll()">
    create the code
   </button>
  </fieldset>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is written so that the user only receives a random number with just one click on the button, that is, if the user clicks the button again, he will not receive a new random number;But if you click the Reload button on the browser page and then click the Generate number button, it will receive a new random number.

How can I now turn off the Reload button on the browser page for my site?
That is, if the user clicks on the Reload button on his browser page, the site does not reload and the user can not receive another new random number.
I would disable the reload button in the browser for my site. After receiving a random number and clicking on the Reload button on their browser page, users will not load the site and they will not be able to add another random number.

And another problem:

After the user received the random number and closed the site, and after re-requesting to open the browser through the browser's history and get a new random number, the URL does not exist in history, how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

first thing you should remove form from your html and to achieve what you want you should use localStorage

your Html code

```
  <h1>random number</h1>
  <label>code</label>
  <span id="spnCode">0</span>
  <button id="generate_btn" class="button" onclick="roll()">
  create the code
  </button>
```

your javascript code

```
 $(function() {
   if (localStorage.getItem("clicked") === 'true') {
     $('#generate_btn').prop("disabled", true);
   }
 });


 function roll() {
   //create variables for form elements
   var spnCode = document.getElementById("spnCode");
   //get the ceiling
   var code = 1325 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 36);
   spnCode.innerHTML = code;
   localStorage.setItem("clicked", true);
   console.log(localStorage.getItem("clicked"));
   $('#generate_btn').prop("disabled", true);

 }
```

and css code

```
fieldset {
  width: 600px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 1em;
  clear: left;
}

span {
  float: left;
}

button {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin: auto;
}
```

and you should also include jquery because i have used jquery you can do it in javascript also.
see the [Jsfedded to see working code](https://jsfiddle.net/tangocharile/y6orydxs/)

and this code is for to remove localStorage when browser is closed

```
$(window).unload(function(){
  localStorage.removeItem("clicked");
});
```